# Send previousItem to click event handler in *ngFor

Tags: angular

Is it possible for me to send the previous value of some item in an `*ngFor` when handling some event such as `click()`? For example:

```
<myElement *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div (click)="onClick(item, previousItem)">
</myElement>
```

That way I can alter that state of the previousItem before setting some property on the current item.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index

```
<myElement *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <div (click)="onClick(item, i > 0 ? items[i - 1] : null)">
</myElement>
```

Comment: I should've been more specific. Suppose it's any index, by previous, I mean the last item that was clicked, not necessarily the previous one before it. So if I click on `item 3` from `item 1`, I'd like to get the item at 1. Thanks

Comment: Just assign the previously clicked item to a field (in `onClicked`) so that you have it available when another one is clicked, and then at the end of `onClicked` assign the currently clicked to have it available next time, ...